# Golang test coverage when test files outside package

Tags: unit-testing, go, testing, code-coverage

I am trying to get the proper coverage amount of my code in the processor package using my test files that are in the test directory. I've tried numerous combinations of -cover and -coverpkg and cannot get it to work correctly. Can this be done while having the test files in separate package/folder?

```
.
├── internal
│   └── processor
└── test
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tracked down an answer and this is how I was able to accomplish my goal:

```
go test -cover -coverpkg "./internal/processor" "./test"
```

Based on [cmd/go, Testing Flags](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-Testing_flags), the flag usage is:

`-coverpkg pattern1,pattern2,pattern3`

> Apply coverage analysis in each test to packages matching the patterns.
> **The default is for each test to analyze only the package being tested.**
> See 'go help packages' for a description of package patterns.    Sets -cover.